# How to set default YouTube video to flash and default quality to 480p with greasemonkey script?

Tags: youtube, userscripts

I try [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50302/how-to-set-a-default-video-quality-on-all-youtube-videos) and it doesn't worked since YouTube tend to load video in HTML5 and that forced most of the video I see to 720/360p only (no 480p) so I need YouTube to run flash-player instead (I Google a bit and found I can force it to run flash by add "&nohtml5=1" at the end of all url, but that doesn't automatically change quality to 480p).

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I use the FF extension [YouTube Flash Video Player](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-video-player) to do this.
In Options set it to Flash Video Player.

Comment: thank you, flashplayer problem solved.

the rest is just change default quality :)

Comment: @goodknife It's great to hear that this resolved the problem for you! Could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If only 360/720p is available, it means that DASH is not available, either because you're using a userscript specifically preventing it, or because you're using a rather old browser which doesn't support MSE.

If you're using a unmodified up-to-date browser, you don't need to do anything: All resolutions are available there, and if you manually select a  quality, your selection gets stored in a cookie for a month or so.